# Как начать использовать Dev Extreme?

Tags: html, visual-studio, devexpress

Задание от рук. практики: HTML страница с 12 текстовыми полями с использованием DevExpress. После загрузки и установки триал версии - встал в тупик. Я вообще думал что это отдельная среда разработки. Немного разобравшись - нашел новый шаблон в Visual Studio во вкладке C#/Web: Dev Extreme MVC 5 application.  Запустив - не обнаружил в структуре проекта  HTML файл совсем, да и громоздкий он какой-то.   Других шаблонов нет. Упорно не понимаю с чего начать.  Документация рассчитана на опытных разработчиков,а не на тех кто слышит об этом впервые. От руководителя помощи не жди. Я вообще не совсем понимаю в чем должно заключаться использование Dev Extreme применительно к странице. Но видимо обеспечивать мультиплатформенность проекта. (Коротко о проекте: web приложение для промышленного терминала, имеющее несколько полей ввода(№товара, партия и т.д), бек энд: -  C#, MS Dynamics AX. В случае потери соединения - сохранение данных в лок. хранилище  и авт. отправка при восстановлении соединения). Собственно вопрос: с чего начать реализацию фронт энда в контексте описанного мной проекта и выбранных технологий?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Павел,

советую вам написать ребятам в отдел поддержки по адресу https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create (необходима регистрация)
Вам определенно помогут взяться за девекстрим с правильного места. Поскольку официально язык, на котором осуществляется поддержка, английский, не стесняйтесь пользоваться любым онлайн переводчиком, если испытываете затруднения в описании сценария использования или сошлитесь на вопрос тут. 
П.С. С DynamicsAX - мощно.